# How Kyoka Suigetsu is still in harmony with Aizen?

Tags: bleach

> While Kōga sitting alone in a cave, Muramasa appeared and asked him why he would kill innocent bystanders, which prompted Kōga to claim he was teaching Soul Society a lesson for exiling him from their world. Soon, Kōga was even abusing Muramasa when he was anything less than absolutely obedient. This disharmony between them gradually caused Kōga to lose his ability to communicate with Muramasa, or even access his power.
>
> Bleach anime; Episode 251

If killing innocent bystanders can make a Zanpakuto feel bad and revolt to its master, why wouldn't Kyoka Suigetsu revolt against Aizen?

Answer (score 1):

The entire premise you're referring to is during a filler arc, and thus, would not have any satisfactory answer to any plot holes that were left.  This is one such plot hole.

That said, speaking more general to the series, it is not known what kind of relationship Kyoka Suigetsu and Aizen have with each other, given that we have never seen a bankai, nor have we seen  Kyoka Suigetsu directly communicate with Aizen on any level.  It is easy to presume that it's quite strained given the level of abuse it has suffered due to Aizen fusing with the Hogyoku, which ultimately led it to break, but we simply don't know.

It's also worth noting that Muramasa only impacted Zanpakuto that he was able to directly come in contact with.  Aizen was not in Soul Society during this filler arc, so Muramasa could never have communed with Kyoka Suigetsu to cause it to rebel.

Comment: I'd also add that not all the zanpakto might have a problem with killing people.  Kazeshini for instance ([https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lLJuJF-mg3s](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lLJuJF-mg3s)) seems more than happy to murder things.

Comment: I wasnt asking about contacting kyoka suigetsu. Im asking why aizen can still access kyoka Suigetsu after being abused

Comment: @LordSacha Likely for the same reason that Mayuri can still access his.